# Redux-form: form is undefined in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, reducers

I am trying to get a redux-form working but am getting a warning that says:

```
Unexpected property "form" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer property names instead: "route", "questionSet". Unexpected properties will be ignored.
```

When I console.log the props to see my form, form is undefined.
I believe the problem is in the configuration.

my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import './index.css';
import App from './containers/App/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './configureStore'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

// import { configureStore } from "redux-inject-reducer-and-saga";
const initialState = {};
const history = createHistory();
const store = configureStore(initialState, createHistory);
ReactDOM.render(  <Provider store={store}>
                  <App />
              </Provider>,
              document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

this is my storeConfig.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import createReducer from './rootReducer';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default function configureStore(initialState, history) {
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)];
  
  const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];
  const composeEnhancers =
   process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
          shouldHotReload: false,
        })
      : compose;

  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers),
  );

  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  store.injectedReducers = {};
  store.injectedSagas = {}; 

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./rootReducer', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers));
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

This is my RootReducer:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
// import { routeReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form/immutable';


export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  console.log(formReducer, 'form')
  return combineReducers({
    // route: routeReducer,

    ...injectedReducers,
    form: formReducer
  });
}
```

Need more text to post (will replace): I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.I can also add the rootReducer in a minute.

Comment: can you share your './configureStore.js' file ..

Comment: Have you registered the `form` reducer? https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-1-of-4-form-reducer

Comment: From the code, it looks like you haven't. Please start with getting started guide. https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/#getting-started-with-code-redux-form-code-

Comment: @HardikModha. I have, just didn't get my code up fast enough.

Comment: @AshishKumar, question is updated

Comment: @LeighLawhon can you try import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable'

Comment: @AshishKumar, no change. still getting undefined for the form